# Como pegar nome de cidades que estão ao meu redor com API em um servidor remoto?

Tags: api

Atualmente utilizo as linhas de código abaixo para listar a cidade onde estou através de latitude e longitude, porém, com as mesmas coordenadas, quero que liste também as cidades que estão ao redor, por quilometragem por exemplo. É possível? Pesquisei bastante sobre isto mas não encontrei uma solução.

Segue o código que estou utilizando para puxar a cidade atual:

```
 $latitude = htmlspecialchars($_GET["latitude"]);
       $longitude = htmlspecialchars($_GET["longitude"]); 
       $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$latitude.','.$longitude.'&sensor=false');
        $resultado = json_decode($geocode);


          for($j=0;$j<count($resultado->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
               $cn=array($resultado->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]);
           if(in_array("locality", $cn))
           {
            $s = $resultado->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
           }
            }
```

Agradeceria muito se me ajudassem a encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Se a resposta selecionada serviu, sugeriria tirar Google e Google Maps das tags e do título da pergunta, pois a resposta não obtém os resultados do Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei um post que combina o Google Maps Geocoding API com GeoNames.org API para fazer isso que voce quer, segue abaixo o codigo .php

```
$geocodeObject = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={CITY NAME},{COUNTRY CODE}'), true);

//Pegar a latitude e longitude
$latitude = $geocodeObject['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$longitude = $geocodeObject['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

//Entrar com os parametros
$responseStyle = 'short';
$citySize = 'cities15000'; //Voce ainda pode definir um numero minimo de habitantes por cidades
$radius = 30; // Raio em KM
$maxRows = 30;
$username = '{YOUR USERNAME}'; //Seu USERNAME no GeoNames

$nearbyCities = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat='.$latitude.'&lng='.$longitude.'&style='.$responseStyle.'&cities='.$citySize.'&radius='.$radius.'&maxRows='.$maxRows.'&username='.$username, true));

foreach($nearbyCities->geonames as $cityDetails)
{

}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172084/can-i-use-google-api-for-finding-nearest-cities

Espero ter ajudado :)

Att. Jeiferson

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado...

Comment: Não vi vantagem em pegar as coordenadas do google, já que vai usar GeoNames para obter as cidades vizinhas. Poderia pegar tudo do GeoNames diretamente.

Comment: Exatamente isso que fiz, uma vez que quem envia as coordenadas para o servidor são os dispositivos mobile. Então a partir da linha $responseStyle = 'short'; o código resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Testei o mesmo e está dando o seguinte erro: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized. Eu criei a conta e mesmo assim está dando esse erro. Sabe o que pode ser?